# Converting CSV to TSV

Tags: text-processing, python, perl, csv

I have a number of large CSV files and would like them in TSV (tab separated format). The complication is that there are commas in the fields of the CSV file, eg:

```
 A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M",Z
```

Expected output:

```
 A      C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

(where whitespace in between are 'hard' tabs)

I have Perl, Python, and coreutils installed on this server.

Comment: I would do this with node.js or with perl.

Comment: Replace non quoted commas with tabs...

Comment: Yes, if I had more than 5 minutes to this question. But I will happily support the answerers with my votes. What I tried to say, that the common sed/awk things are probably ineligible for that (at least in their commonly used usage).

Comment: You've got a solution in a half hour... I think you could have solved it in around the same time. :-) Be more patient :-)

Comment: @peterh - fair point

Comment: Just about every programming language has a CSV parsing library. And typically those libraries can handle quotes as used in your example. The tricky part about this question is that there are too many good answers. Perhaps with some constraints it can be narrowed down to a programming language, and from there a library.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - Noted - updated question with the languages that I have available to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if your example is representative of the actual data, but if those are going to be actual text strings then don't forget that you may need to handle the case where the string includes a tab...

Comment: The other tricky part is that CSV is a very loosely defined format, there is no real standard (there is a RFC but it was written years after the fact). I have written code that used a language-supplied CSV parser and then had to rewrite it with a custom parser because I found the input data was in a broken variant of the csv format.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Python

Add to file named `csv2tab`, and make it executable

`touch csv2tab && chmod u+x csv2tab`

Add to it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv, sys
csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))
```

#### Test runs

```
$ echo 'A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M",Z' | ./csv2tab                     
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

```
$ ./csv2tab < data.csv > data.tsv && head data.tsv                                                   
1A      C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
2A      C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
3A      C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

Comment: i get the following error when I try your solution: `No protocol specified
import-im6.q16: unable to open X server :0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/358.
csv2tab.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token sys.stdout,'
csv2tab.sh: line 3: csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))'`

Comment: @kev This code doesn't require an X Server, so seems you may have some other issue

Answer (score 33):

Using [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvformat.html) (Python), for example:

```
$ csvformat -T in.csv > out.txt
```

Does streaming, with correct CSV and TSV quoting and escaping

It's in apt and other package managers

Comment: Command line I used to fix the quoting: csvformat -U 3 -Q "" -T in.csv > out.tsv

Answer (score 25):

For fun, `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g' file
```

If your `sed` doesn't support `-E`, try with `-r`.  If your `sed` doesn't support `\t` for a literal tab, try putting a literal tab (in many shells, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>) or in Bash, use a `$'...'` C-style string (in which case the backslash in `\2` needs to be doubled).  If you want to keep the quotes, use `\1` instead of `\2` (in which case the inner pair of parentheses is useless, and can be removed).

If your `sed` doesn't support either `-E` or `-r`, try

```bsh
sed 's/\("\([^"]*\)"\)\?,/\2\t/g' file
```

again possibly with the tweaks suggested above if `\t` is not supported.

For additional fun, here's the same thing with the Bash "here-string" syntax, just to demonstrate what it looks like. Notice how the literal backslashes we want `sed` to receive are now doubled:

```bsh
sed $'s/\\("\\([^"]*\\)"\\)\\?,/\\2\t/g' file
```

This makes no attempt to handle escaped double quotes inside double quotes; some CSV dialects support this by doubling the quoted double quote (sic).

Comment: I think that i tried about 100 different sed scripts to achieve this one but all my attempts failed. This is awesome.

Comment: your command works with my sed version (4.4). Unfortunatly with another Linux the sed version is 4.2.2 and don't work with the same data, even after replace `-E` by `-r`. Do you have a clue how to fix that ? Thanks

Comment: @nstatam If you get an error message for both `-E` and `-r`, you will need to refactor to a POSIX BRE regex (see updated answer now). If you don't, I'm guessing you transcribed the script incorrectly. Did you try with a literal tab instead of the symbolic sequence `\t`? Which Linux distro exactly is this?

Comment: Great answer, but note that it doesn't strip the double quotes from the final field if there is no trailing comma (e.g. `"a","b"` becomes `a<TAB>"b"`). This can be fixed by appending a comma at the start, then removing the corresponding trailing tab afterward: `sed -E 's/$/,/; s/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g; s/\t$//'`

Answer (score 14):

One option might be perl's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.94/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module e.g.

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne 'BEGIN { $csv = Text::CSV->new() }
  print join "\t", $csv->fields() if $csv->parse($_)
' somefile
```

to demonstrate

```
echo 'A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M",Z' |
  perl -MText::CSV -lne 'BEGIN { $csv = Text::CSV->new() }
  print join "\t", $csv->fields() if $csv->parse($_)
'
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

Comment: Wouldn't be correct if a field contains a tab

Answer (score 8):

## Perl

```
perl -lne '
   my $re = qr/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))/;
   print join "\t", map { s/(?<!\\)"//gr =~ s/\\"/"/gr } split $re;
'
```

## Awk

```
awk -v Q=\" -v FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS="\t" '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ( substr($i, 1, 1) == Q )
         $i = substr($i, 2, length($i) - 2)
   print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8
}'
```

Result:

```
A               C       D,E,F   G       I       K,L,M   Z
```

Comment: +1 Perl version works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

I authored an open-source CSV to TSV converter that handles the transformations described. It's quite fast, may be worth a look if there's an on-going need to convert large CSV files. Tool is part of [eBay's TSV utilities toolkit](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils) (csv2tsv documentation [here](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/csv2tsv.html)). Default options suffice for the input described:

```
$ csv2tsv file.csv > file.tsv
```

A consideration when converting CSV to TSV is handling of field and record delimiters (comma and newline) in the data. CSV uses an escape syntax. If the goal is to use the output with Unix tools like `cut`, `awk`, etc., the output needs to be free of escapes. Most solutions listed here produce CSV style escapes when delimiters are in the data. `csv2tsv` is differentiated from other solutions in that it produces TSV without escapes. See the documentation for details.

To see what a particular solution does, convert a CSV containing commas, tabs, quotes, and newlines in the data. For example:

```
$ echo $'Line,Field1,Field2\n1,"Comma: |,|","Quote: |""|"\n"2","TAB: |\t|","Newline: |\n|"' | <conversion-script-or-command>
```

Solutions generating escapes will put double quotes around the fields containing quotes, newlines, or tabs.

Answer (score 6):

The thermonuclear flyswatter solution must be using libreoffice. While https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19042/is-is-possible-to-convert-comma-separated-value-csv-to-tab-separated-value-tsv-via-headless-mode/ suggests this is not possible but it is wrong (or just outdated?) and the following command works on my 5.3.:

`loffice  "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibO_Conversion"  --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":9,34,UTF8 --headless --outdir some/path --infilter='csv:44,34,UTF8' *.csv`

the `env` argument could be skipped but this way the documents won't appear in your recent document.

Comment: I think the true thermonuclear flyswatter would be writing a Java utility to do it via LibreOffice's UNO API :).

Answer (score 6):

If you have, or can install, the `csvtool` utility:

```
csvtool -t COMMA -u TAB cat in.csv > out.ctv
```

Note that for some reason `csvtool` doesn't have a man page, but `csvtool --help` will print a couple hundred lines of documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is almost succinct, but disabling headers requires long options:

```bash
mlr --c2t --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cat file.csv
```

Newer releases of Miller combine these long options into a single `-N` option:

```bash
mlr --c2t -N cat file.csv
```

Output:

```
A               C       D,E,F   G       I       K,L,M   Z
```

Comment: I didn't see anything in the original question about disabling headers.  When I decided to use `mlr` to convert a CSV file (with headers) to an equivalent TSV file (keeping headers, naturally), I just used:

`mlr --c2t cat input.csv > output.tsv`

The results were perfect.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan If the file _only_ contains a line such as the one shown in the question, and if you don't tell `mlr` to read the data without a header, then the output will be empty.

Comment: I understand.  I applied the solution to a similar problem, but I'd forgotten that the original question used input **_without_** column headers.

Answer (score 2):

## **Vim**

Just for fun, regex substitutions can be performed in **Vim**.  Here's a potential four line solution, adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332871/remove-all-commas-between-quotes-with-a-vim-regex

1. Commas between quotes are first changed to underscores (or other absent character),
2. All other commas are replaced with tabs,
3. Underscores inside quotes are restored to commas,
4. Quotation marks are removed.

   ```
   :%s/".\{-}"/\=substitute(submatch(0), ',', '_' , 'g')/g
   :%s/,/\t/g
   :%s/_/,/g
   :%s/"//g
   ```

To script the solution somewhat, the four lines above (sans leading colon) can be saved to a file, e.g. `to_tsv.vim`. Open each CSV for editing with **Vim** and `source` the `to_tsv.vim` script on the **Vim** command line (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374179/run-vim-script-from-vim-commandline/8806874#8806874):

```
    :source /path/to/vim/filename/to_tsv.vim
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, assuming the csv fields have no embedded `"` or newlines or tabs:

```
perl -pe 's{"(.*?)"|,}{$1//"\t"}ge'
```

Comment: obfuscated but very cool!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of converting CSV into TSV using [`jq` utility](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/645#issuecomment-68064437):

```
$ jq -rn '@tsv "\(["A","","C","D,E,F","G","I","K,L,M","Z"])"'
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

or:

```
$ echo '["A","","C","D,E,F","G","I","K,L,M","Z"]' | jq -r @tsv
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

However the CSV format needs to be well formatted, so each string needs to be quoted.

<sup>Source: [Simple TSV output format](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/645).</sup>

Comment: This does not convert CSV to TSV. It converts a list of JSON strings to TSV.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution (with requirements): One really should also handle literal double-quotes, which are represented by a pair of double-quotes within a CSV field.

First change all such double-quote literals to a stand-in flag; then delete all field delimiters (solitary double-quotes), and convert field separators (commas) to tabs; then change the stand-in flags to double-quotes.

Here I'm using `\v` (vertical tab) as the stand-in flag for embedded double-quotes:

`sed -r 's/""/\v/g; s/("([^"]+)")?,/\2\t/g; s/\v/"/g\'`

This solution relies on your CSV data *not containing vertical-tab characters*, and on empty CSV fields *not* being quoted.

Comment: This version also works if a line ends with a double-quoted field: `echo '1337,"test input"'|sed -r 's/""/\v/g;s/("([^"]+)")?,/\2\t/g;s/"([^"]+)"$/\1/;s/\v/"/g'` (the dollar sign is not required, but it's used to clarify the intent of the command). Both your and my version fail when a field consists of 4 double quotes (i.e. a single double quote in escaped form): `"next field is a single escaped double quote",""""`.

Answer (score 1):

After `gem install csv`:

```
$ time </tmp/a ruby -rcsv -e'puts CSV.parse($<).map{|x|x*"\t"}'>/dev/null
0.307
$ time ruby -rcsv -e'CSV.foreach("/tmp/a"){|x|puts x*"\t"}'>/dev/null
0.367
$ time </tmp/a ruby -rcsv -ne'puts CSV.parse($_)*"\t"'>/dev/null
2.456
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is simply a correction to [the answer from *@tripleee*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359873/29186) 
so that it strips any quotes from the final field just as it does to all the other fields.

To show what's being corrected, below is a *tripleee*'s answer, plus a slight modification to the OP's example data with added quotes around the final '*Z*' field.

```
echo 'A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M","Z"' |  sed -r -e 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g'
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   "Z"
```

You can see that '*Z*' is left with quotes around it.  This is different to how the inner fields are handled.  For example, the '*G*' does not have quotes on it.

The following command uses a second substitution to clean the final column:

```
echo 'A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M","Z"' |  sed -r -e 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g' \
                                                -e 's/\t"([^"]*)"$/\t\1/'
A       C   D,E,F   G   I   K,L,M   Z
```

Comment: When the input data `'A,,C,"D,E,F","G",I,"K,L,M","Z,A"'` is input to this answer, then the `"Z,A"` is incorrectly replaced with `Z             A`, rather than the correct `Z,A`.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing context sensitive formats is indeed a constant annoyance esp. when csv quoting is inconsistent and even irregular.  Here is some straightforward awk that anyone ought to be able to use/revise.  It's not as clever as terse awk, but perhaps a good building block that is easily tweaked.  Yes, I know it could be shortened, but I like reusable awk to have a bit of slack.

```
{
  mark[++nmark] = 0
  thislength = length($0)
  for (i=1; i<=thislength; i++) {
    thisc = substr($0,i,1)
    if (thisc == "\\") { i++; continue } # skip \x for any x
    if (thisc == "\"") qflag = 1-qflag
    if (thisc == "," && !qflag) mark[++nmark] = i
  }
  mark[++nmark] = thislength+1
  for (i=1; i<nmark; i++) {
    thiso = outfield[++noutfield] = substr($0, mark[i]+1, mark[i+1]-mark[i]-1)
    if (thiso ~ /^".*"$/) {
      sub(/"$/,"",outfield[noutfield])
      sub(/^"/,"",outfield[noutfield])
    }
  }
  for (i=1; i<noutfield; i++) printf "%s", outfield[i]"\t"
  print outfield[noutfield]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using Python and Pandas:

```bash
python -c 'import sys; import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]).to_csv(sys.argv[2], sep="\t", index=False)' input.csv output.tsv
```

Formatted for readability:

```bash
python -c '
import sys
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]).to_csv(sys.argv[2], sep="\t", index=False)
' input.csv output.tsv
```