# csv to tsv with nested quoting

Tags: text-processing, csv

I need to convert CSV to TSV in bash. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359873/42081) solution and it works well, but not for all datasets as I will show below.

For example, for `a.txt`:

```
a,"test, part2 ""the start""",b
```

`sed` format it badly:

```
[ nir ]$ cat a.txt | sed -E 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g' 
a    "test    Op. 15 ""the start"    b
#^ tab....^ tab..................^ tab
```

Issues here: missing `,`, extra tab, extra quotes.

Just to reference even python code format it badly:

```
[ nir ]$ cat a.txt | csv2tsv.py
a    "test, part2 ""the start"""    b
#^ tab..........................^ tab
```

Issues here: extra quotes.

`csv2tsv.py` is:
`csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))`

Where the true convert should looks like:

```
a    test, part2 "the start"    b
#^ tab......................^ tab
```

Would love to get some feedback how to solve this in `bash`. I went over many solution in the internet but non managed to handle those quotes on quotes inside quotes :)

Comment: Did you try `tr ',' '\t' < a.txt`  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting CSV to TSV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359832/converting-csv-to-tsv)

Comment: In my question I actually link to that solution, and not it is not. The multiple quotes breaks it. as for the `tr` it will not work as it does not consider the quotes

Comment: At least one of the answers in [the suggested duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359832/100397) will work for your example data. Don't just try the accepted answer

Comment: You've provided one line of test code. Could you give us a little more to work with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `mlr`:

```
mlr -N --icsv --otsvlite cat < file.csv > file.tsv
```

Or:

```
mlr -N --c2t --quote-none cat < file.csv > file.tsv
```

But note that if a csv field contains a tab character, it will end up not escaped in the output and therefore introducing an extra field.

With GNU `sed`, you could do the same with:

```
sed -E '
  # append next line as long as there is not an even number
  # of "s, to handle fields with newline. You can omit this line
  # if the fields are guaranteed not to contain newlines:
  :1; /^([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$/! {N;b1}

  s/$/,/
  s/(([^,"]*)|"((""|[^"])*)"),/\2\3\t/g
  s/\t$//
  s/""/"/g' < file.csv > file.tsv
```

That assumes the input is valid text in the current locale. Start `sed` as `LC_ALL=C sed...` to disable localisation and treat the input as if it was binary input to avoid decoding issues (and likely speed things up if speed is a concern)

Comment: We can assume there is no, new line. but since you already provided an answer for this scenario. can you post 2 options? (one with newline consideration and one w/o)

Comment: @Nir, see edit.

Comment: Looks great and works well!! Thanks!! I would love a comment describing  `s/(([^,"]*)|"((""|[^"])*)"),/\2\3\t/g` so I can learn from it ;)

Comment: the new `sed` command is extremely slow

Answer (score 4):

bash 5.1 comes with a loadable CSV module

```bsh
BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/\/bin\//\/lib\/}
enable -f csv csv
csv -a fields "$line"
new_line=$(IFS=$'\t'; echo "${fields[*]}")
declare -p line fields new_line
```

outputs

```bsh
declare -- line="a,\"test, part2 \"\"the start\"\"\",b"
declare -a fields=([0]="a" [1]="test, part2 \"the start\"" [2]="b")
declare -- new_line="a  test, part2 \"the start\"   b"
#.....................^ tab......................^ tab
```

This is not valid is there's a field containing a tab.

---

In a pipeline:

```bsh
IFS=$'\t'
cat file |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    csv -a fields "$line"
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done |
tail
```

Although this is more idiomatic bash

```bsh
IFS=$'\t'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    csv -a fields "$line"
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < file | tail
```

Comment: Can you please show how to use it as part of pipe?  for example `cat a.txt | <convert> | tail`

Comment: Note that few systems ship those loadable bash builtins by default as they're more like example code (and not much tested). That `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/\/bin\//\/lib\/}` will likely not work if bash is found in `/bin` (which it is most of the time).

Comment: That csv builtin was added in 5.1. It was not there in 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Or use [`csvformat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) from the [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) -- this tool takes care of quoting any field containing the delimiter: I added a line to the input file that has tabs in it.

```bsh
$ cat a.txt
a,"test, part2 ""the start""",b
c,d,e   with    tabs

$ csvformat -D $'\t' a.txt
a   "test, part2 ""the start""" b
c   d   "e  with    tabs"
```

Comment: The `"` should not be in the result

Comment: The second line needs quotes to contain the inner delimiters. For the first line, [the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) says "If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
       double quotes may not appear inside the fields." But the standard is merely advisory: if you don't want to follow it, then don't, but common CSV tools (like csvkit) may not meet your requirements